# invalid csrf token in wikidata api even on logging in through java

Tags: java, jsoup, csrf, wikidata, wikidata-api

I was making a request to wikidata for editing a label through java. Here below I used Jsoup to make a request.

```
Response res = (Response) Jsoup.connect("https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=Wikidata%3AMain+Page")
        .method(Method.POST)
        .timeout(10000)
        .execute();
```

The cookies obtained via this response is used in login to wiki via its api (so as to get csrf token which is required for changing labels of entities).

First a login token was generated.

```
String url = "https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&meta=tokens&type=login";

org.jsoup.nodes.Document loginData =  Jsoup.connect(url)
        .data("action","query")
        .data("format","xml","meta","tokens","type","login")
        .cookies(res.cookies())
        .get();
```

Then login was done

```
 org.jsoup.nodes.Document loginData1 =  Jsoup.connect(url)
        .data("action","login")   
        .data("format","xml","lgname",username,"lgpassword",password,"lgtoken",loginToken)
        .cookies(res.cookies())
        .post();
```

The login was done successfully.

Now for getting csrf token

```
loginData =  Jsoup.connect(url)
        .data("action","query")
        .data("format","xml","meta","tokens","type","csrf")
        .cookies(res.cookies())
        .get();
```

Here csrf token is generated as: +\

But since I am logging in why such invalid token is generated?And hence I was not able to set label through my java program.What is the correct way?

Comment: The first request to Special:UserLogin is not necessary. When getting a login token, why do you send parameters in both the query string and as post data? Is it the same url you use in the other requests? Otherwise your api parameters seems correct, but I'm not a java programmer so I don't know Jsoup.

Comment: The first request to Special:UserLogin to get res.cookies() which are later used for getting login token and logging in as well as generating csrf token.

Comment: The url used in others(i.e. login and csrf token) is :                                     url = "https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?";

Comment: Does that mean you do not store the cookie you get when logging in? If so, that's the problem. Again, the first request should not be necessary.